# what is network programming

Tags: tcp

I've completed a program using java under eclipse, i have converted my code to .jar file and proceed to converting the .jar file to .exe file, I've even created an installer in connection to my .exe file.  Every time i use the program to encode data, all of the data are recorded in the folder where my .exe file is located (to my local hard drive), the program is working just fine.  The problem is, the concept of my program is not only to use it on my computer(one of the working station in our LAN) but also to deploy it to our local area network where in, i can encode data from one of our computer stations(client) and save those data to our server's hard disk and not to the computer station(client) hard disk as my current program is doing.  I've made some research on how to achieved the concept of encoding data from a working station and save the data to the server's hard disk, so far i came up with TCP/IP programing and network programing.  My question is, am i in the right path?  If i proceed with this part of java will I achieved my goal or is there any other way of achieving my concept.  I'm not really asking anybody to teach me how to achieved this goal, i am merely asking if I'm in the right path(study TCP/IP and network programing) or if i should study other part of java to achieved this concept.  Please consider my way of asking, i feel very elementary, to be honest i have very less idea on TCP/IP programing and if TCP/IP is the correct topic to study to achieved my concept.  Hoping that someone could give me a tip on this matter.  Thank you and more power to stackoverflow.

Comment: you should import your questions format

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve your solution using network programming by writing a client and server, but depending on your needs it may not be the simplest solution.

For example, if you use the program from only one workstation at a time, you can output to a file saved on a shared network drive such as a windows shared folder or using nfs.
If you can set up a shared drive or folder from your sever that is accessible to all the workstations you are using, you can simply alter your program to read and write the data file into the network-shared directory.

If this will not work for you, then go ahead with learning sockets programming.

I suggest looking through the official documentation to get started:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/